# do you need wifi or 3G for CLLocationManager getting current location? - iphone

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocationmanager

Can CLLocationManager getCurrentLocation work without wifi or a cellular network? with the inbuilt GPS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iPod Touch, yes. 
For iPhone, no.

iPod Touch doesn't have a built-in GPS receiver and it uses WiFi hot spot signatures for approximation.

The iPhone does have a built-in GPS receiver, so it works fine without 3G or WiFi.

Proof? Drive down the thruway and you'll go outside of 3G/Edge network, but Google Maps still tracks your current location.

Comment: thats great if it does. Just tried on my iPad by switching off wifi and it does not work, but I am counting on your point that on the iphone it will work.

Comment: Only 3G models of the iPad have a built-in GPS receiver.

Comment: Steve, I just tried it on the iphone, and does not seem to work. I switched off 3G and wifi. My custom app has location check info, and it does not update any location on it :( (it updates with previously saved one, but does not update any new one - control does not go to that method)

Comment: Switched off 3G, or went out of range of 3G? I think there is a difference.

Comment: I switched off 3G and saw the same thing... but I know that when I go out of range of 3G it does still work. I'd bet turning off 3G also disables the GPS chip (why would you turn off 3G?)

Comment: switched off..I am going abroad so wanted to check if I can use location services, without being connected to wifi and without using data roaming.

Comment: You can turn off data-roaming in particular. You don't need to turn off 3G to do that.

Comment: ok, so do you mean that with 3G on, it would not cost me anything for accessing location based services? (with data roaming off and wifi unavailable)

Answer (score 2):

---

I cannot find any documentation that confirms either yes or no, but from my experience I'd say yes. Core Location uses cell towers, wifi, and gps together to find your location so if one or two of the services are unavailable I would assume the system would use whatever resource it can. If it doesn't seem to work, it could be (I'm just guessing here) that you have to set the desired accuracy to something high (try kCLLocationAccuracyBest) in order for GPS to kick in.

If you haven't already, check out the video "What's new in Core Location" https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the gps go to maps, after turning the 3g and wifi off, and click the location icon on the bottom. then you will see loading and then it will give you the current location